# Problems with facebook php sdk v4

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, drupal, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to get facebook php sdk v4 to work with my app. I am using Drupal and an nginx server with phpfpm.

When I try to get the session from facebook sdk, I get the error - Missing redirect uri parameter. While debugging, I found 2 strange things are happening -

1) If I copy and paste the get url(generated by the sdk) in my browser, a valid access token is returned.

2) If I change the method for retrieving the access token from GET(default) to POST in the sdk, a valid access token is returned to my app.

Also, when using the access token I received from POST call, if I make further GET requests to the graph api, none of them work.

However, if I make a POST request, such as posting to my wall, it works.

Also it should be noted that the sdk is internally using curl to make all requests.

Edit :
Code Example - 
To generate login url

```
$helper = new \Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($this->redirectUrl);
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('public_profile', 'email', 'user_friends', 'publish_actions'));
```

Now the person is taken to facebook for authentication and redirected to my redirect url. Here the code is -

```
$helper = new \Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($this->redirectUrl);
$session = helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
```

Since getSessionFromRedirect internally uses a GET call, it doesn't work for me. When I change the sdk code to use POST, a valid access token is returned.

Also when I get a valid session using a POST request, this works

```
$response = (new FacebookRequest(
        $session, 'POST', '/me/feed', array(
            'link' => 'www.example.com',
            'message' => 'User provided message'
        )
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject();
```

But this doesn't work -

```
$user_profile = (new FacebookRequest(
      $session, 'GET', '/me'
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

    echo "Name: " . $user_profile->getName();
```

Clearly there seems to be an issue with all the GET requests. Any hints on what can be the problem?

Comment: Can you maybe provide some examples of the calls you make? Both for getting the session and the GET calls you make?

Comment: yeah sure, adding them!

Comment: Thanks. Using your retrieved access token, can you replicate the problems in the Graph Explorer? (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

Comment: No I can't. As I said, even if I simply copy and paste the url (with the query parameters) into my browser, it works. But the GET calls made by the sdk don't seem to work at all.

Comment: If your app is a Canvas App or a Page App, then yes, you need to use POST to retrieve the session data. GET will work for website / off-Facebook apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem finally. Turns out drupal is changing the & in url for GET requests to & .
Related to [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3934/problem-with-curl) .